# Verb for adding something to a database or table

Tags: word-request

What verb should be used for adding an entry/row to a table in a database - which is NOT "add"?

**Edit**

Searching "Word for adding row to database" or the similar sort does not give any helpful results

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL doesn't do variable name suggestions for programming contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It is not really a variable name, that just happens to be the situation I am in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is well defined in database documentation.

Comment: @CJDennis Which database documentation?

Comment: @Marvin All of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **enter** data.

> I entered some data into the spreadsheet.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/enter)

> **enter**
>   VERB
>
> **3** Write or key (information) in a book, computer, etc.

Comment: Also, you can [**extend**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/extend) a table, when you add a row or column.

Comment: After some criteria have been met beyond just typing it in, you might say "accept".

Answer (score 6):

`INSERT`, if you want to be [technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)) about it.